# Multiclient server in Python - how to broadcast?

Tags: python, sockets

I found online a simple multiclient echo server in Python using threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys
import threading

class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, connection):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

    def run(self):

        data = self.connection.recv(1024)
        if data :
            self.connection.sendall(data)
        else :
            self.connection.close()

class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.address = (self.ip, self.port)
        self.server = None
        self.clients = []

    def open_socket(self):
        try:
            self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server.bind(self.address)
        except socket.error, e:
            if self.server:
                self.server.close()
            sys.exit(1)

    def run(self):
        self.open_socket()
        self.server.listen(5)

        while True :
            connection, (ip, port) = self.server.accept()

            c = Client(ip, port, connection)
            c.start()

            self.clients.append(c)

        self.server.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server('127.0.0.1', 6666)
    s.run()
```

And I wrote a client:

```
import socket
import sys

port = 6666
size = 1024
s = None
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
except socket.error, (value, message):
    if s:
        s.close()
    print "Could not open socket: " + message
    sys.exit(1)
data = raw_input('> ')
s.sendall(data)
data = s.recv(size)
print "Server sent: %s " % data
s.close()
```

Everything works great but I wonder how could I add to the server the functionality of broadcast to be able to echo back the message to all connected clients? Or be able to send a message to a specific client?

I have all clients in server's class, but I do not know how to (and where in the server's code, in `Client` class or `Server` class place the code to broadcast and send private messages? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

New server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import sys
import threading

class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, connection):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.connection.recv(1024)
            if data :
                self.connection.sendall(data)
            else :
                break
        self.connection.close()


class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.address = (self.ip, self.port)
        self.server = None
        self.clients = []

    def send_to_all_clients(self, msg):
        for client in self.clients :
            client.connection.send(msg)

    def send_to_client(self, ip, port, msg):
        for client in self.clients :
            if client.ip == ip and client.port == port :
                client.connection.send(msg)

    def open_socket(self):
        try:
            self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server.bind(self.address)
        except socket.error, e:
            if self.server:
                self.server.close()
            sys.exit(1)

    def run(self):
        self.open_socket()
        self.server.listen(5)

        while True :
            connection, (ip, port) = self.server.accept()

            c = Client(ip, port, connection)
            c.start()

            self.clients.append(c)

        self.server.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Server('127.0.0.1', 6666)
    s.run()
```

New client:

```
import socket
import sys

port = 6666
size = 1024
s = None
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
except socket.error, (value, message):
    if s:
        s.close()
    print "Could not open socket: " + message
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    s.sendall(data)
    data = s.recv(size)
    print "Server sent: %s " % data
s.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a list of clients in your `Server` , you could use it in a function like that :

```
def send_to_all_clients(self, msg):  
    for client in self.clients : 
        client.connection.send(msg)
```

Then you can make a function to select a specific client :

```
def send_to_client(self, ip, port, msg): 
    for client in self.clients :  
        if client.ip == ip and client.port == port :  
            client.connection.send(msg)
```

*Note*
It's best to add a `Send()` method to `Client` and call it to send the `msg` instead of using `client.connection.send(msg)`

You could use those functions in the server's `run` method , if you modify it to handle events 
( you could do that with `select.select()` , or with user input ( `KeyboardInterrupt` ) , etc , the design is up to you ) .
Also you should modify both client.py and `Client` , and make them more persistent , because now they `close` as soon as they `sendall` or `recv` .
I hope this gives you some ideas

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do this like that: I would like to broadcast to all clients only when the client send a message formatted like this: `broadcast msgtext`, and only then. But at server's side, I do not have the access to the message from client - the data is in `Client` class, while clients are in `Server` class ... I updated my question but still cant find the answer. Could you please help ...?

Comment: You could add a 'message' attribute to `Client` ( eg `self.msg = None` ) and have the `Server` check its value .  Ie : `for client in self.clients : if client.msg == 'broadcast msgtext' : self.send_to_all_clients(client.msg) ; client.msg = None` ( reset it to `None` so you dont send the same message over and over )

Comment: You 'll need to modify the while loop in `Server.run` to check the `client.msg` . You can do this either by setting a timeout in `Server.server` and a try - except in the loop , or with `select.select()` . [Here](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/) you will find an example for the latter.